# export/extern&шаблоны

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Интересно, почему export шаблонов deprecated? Знаю только то, что никто не реализовал ее в своих компиляторах кроме компании Edison Design Group, но потом и они признали что это полная "лажа". В чем были сложности?

В новом стандарте, вместо export tempate ввели extern template. Зачем? Некрофилия?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Проблема следующая. Шаблоны C++ — функциональность, гораздо более близкая к макросам, чем к функциям/классам. Это чистая конструкция времени компиляции. Невозможно «скомпилировать» шаблон так, чтобы потом можно было просто подлинковать его к программе (в отличие от функций и классов.) Поэтому хранить в объектном файле всё равно придётся текст, никакого выигрыша это не даст.

Почему невозможно заранее скомпилировать шаблон в объектный код? Посмотрите на вот такой простой код:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void f(T1 t1)
{
    T2 t2 = t1;
}
```

Это [копирующая инициализация](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). В зависимости от типов `T1` и `T2`, а также от видимости других типов в точке использования она может компилироваться в вызов наилучшего из доступных [конвертирующего конструктора](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) (и преобразование типа `T2` к типу аргумента этого конструктора, если они не совпадают), [оператора конверсии](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), стандартные конверсии, числовые конверсии, включая потерю точности и смену представления между плавающей точкой и целыми числами.

Как вы думаете, можно ли закодировать всё это в объектном коде (то есть, по существу на ассемблере), **не зная** на момент компиляции типы `T1` и `T2`?

---

Вот есть целая статья от EDG, с анализом, почему экспорт шаблонов не взлетит и не стоит свеч: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1426.pdf. И ещё одна: http://blogs.msmvps.com/vandooren/2008/09/24/c-keyword-of-the-day-export/.

Более подробно, проблемы следующие (перевёл из статьи EDG):

1. У EDG на одну эту фичу ушло 1,5 лет на дизайн и 3 года на имплементацию (сравнение: на всю Джаву — только два года). При этом EDG — не «какая-то» компания, у них хорошие разработчики, с многолетним опытом разработки компиляторов C++.
2. Типичная структура компилятора C++ не подходит для имплементации этой фичи. Пришлось переделывать дизайн компилятора, и скорее всего это же придётся сделать всем другим разработчикам, если экспорт станет обязательной частью стандарта.
3. Многие ошибки, которые без экспорта шаблонов было не обязательно детектировать (например, нарушение ODR-rule, которое по стандарту всего лишь UB), с экспортом фактически становится обязательно отлавливать.
4. Форматы промежуточных файлов придётся полностью менять.
5. Эта фича не приносит настолько уж большой пользы:

   - Считается, что с экспортом шаблонов более не нужно будет поставлять исходный код библиотек. Это не так. Поскольку шаблоны работают на уровне, близком к синтаксическому, то вместе с библиотеками придётся поставлять либо текст шаблонов, либо его прямой эквивалент (например, синтаксическое дерево), поскольку во время инстанциации шаблонов нужна вся эта информация.
   - Считается, что с экспортом шаблонов ускорится компиляция и уменьшится количество зависимостей. Это не так, потому что (вследствие синтаксической природы шаблонов) экспортированный шаблон невозможно заранее *скомпилировать*. Компиляцию шаблона (по меньшей мере от уровня синтаксического дерева) придётся всё равно повторять, на этот раз на этапе компоновки. Таким образом, компилятору придётся выполнить *по меньшей мере* ту же работу, что и без экспорта.
   - Единственный реально сработавший плюс экспорта шаблонов — то, что макросы не покидают границы единицы трансляции. (В случае без экспорта, макросы, определённые в файле с шаблоном, «видны» всем, кто использует шаблон.) Этого положительного эффекта, однако, можно добиться при помощи более строгой организации кода; также существуют другие, более лёгкие и эффективные методы решения этой проблемы на уровне стандарта языка.

Comment: Супер, спасибо. Я почитаю эту статью подробней, но если export template непризнан, зачем в новом стандарте добавили extern template?

Comment: @uskabuska: Пожалуйста! extern — это совершенно другая, не связанная с export, вещь.

Comment: @uskabuska: дополнил ответ, может, будет интересно.