# ключевое слово export

Tags: c++

Для чего нужно ключевое слово `export`? Где реально его можно использовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В стандарте C++  в примечании к параграфу №1 раздела 2.12 Keywords написано

> [ Note: The export keyword is unused but is reserved for future
>   use.—end note ]:

То есть это ключевое слово в настоящий момент нигде не используется, но зарезервировано для использования в будущем.

Ранее в стандарте C++ 2003 оно использовалось в определении шаблонов:

> 1 A template defines a family of classes or functions.
>   template-declaration:

```
exportopt template < template-parameter-list > declaration
^^^^^^
```

но было исключено из стандарта. так как это средство не было задействовано многими компиляторами.

Вот пара цитат из с тандарта C++ 2003 (14 Templates), где имеются ссылка на это ключевое слово

> 6 A namespace-scope declaration or definition of a non-inline function
>   template, a non-inline member function template, a non-inline member
>   function of a class template or a static data member of a class
>   template may be preceded by the export keyword. If such a template is
>   defined in the same translation unit in which it is declared as
>   exported, the definition is considered to be exported. The first
>   declaration of the template containing the export keyword must not
>   follow the definition.
>
> 8 Templates defined in an unnamed namespace shall not be exported. A
>   template shall be exported only once in a program. An implementation
>   is not required to diagnose a violation of this rule. A non-exported
>   template must be defined in every translation unit in which it is
>   implicitly instantiated (14.7.1), unless the corresponding
>   specialization is explicitly instantiated (14.7.2) in some translation
>   unit; no diagnostic is required. [Note: See also 14.7.2. ] An exported
>   template need only be declared (and not necessarily defined) in a
>   translation unit in which it is instantiated. A function template
>   declared both exported and inline is just inline and not exported.

Comment: А раньше где использовалось? Просто у меня учебники до ++11

Comment: @andrey2001 Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: @andrey2001, это было реализовано в паре компиляторов, которыми мало кто пользовался, да и там реализовано было непонятно как. Так что можете считать, что этого ключевого слова никогда не было

Comment: Я правильно понял, что это была попытка реализации раздельной компиляции для template?

Comment: @avp  Да, это была попытка не включать определение шаблона в каждую единицу компиляции. В одной из своих книг Герб Саттер подробно описывает это, как я понимаю, собственное провальное предложение по изменению стандарта.

Comment: Спасибо (+1). Вы бы это в ответе указали, многим же (наверное) интересно. А если знаете в чем причина неудачи (я подозреваю проблема с линкером, в т.ч. динамическое связывание с .so при exec?) то тоже напишите.

Comment: @avp Вы уже дополнили ответ своим комментарием.:)

Comment: @avp: О причинах неудачи [вот тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436366/10105) (самореклама).

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, заценил (только м.б. не до конца все проблемы понял, но это уж, наверное, до следующего "всплытия" данной темы).